# How to query row from a value from dropdown menu PHP

Tags: php, dropdown

Below is my code. I want to query a row and print it right away (onchange) after I select from dropdown menu. Please help. thanks.

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'jared17', 'hbadb') 
or die ('Cannot connect to db');

$result = $conn->query("select * from students");

echo "<html>";
echo "<body>";
echo "<form method = POST>";
echo "<select name = 'Students' onchange=this.form.submit()>";

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

              unset($LRN, $First, $Last);
              $LRN = $row['LRN'];
              $First = $row['First_Name'];
              $Last = $row['Last_Name']; 
              echo '<option value="'.$First.'">'.$First.' '.$Last.'</option>';}

echo "</select>";
echo "<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Show'>";
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo "*******I WANT TO QUERY THE ROW I SELECTED IN DROPDOWN MENU****";
    }
echo "</form>";
echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as simple as this

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo $_POST['Students'];
    }
```

**Edit:**
It's better to use `filter_input()` function instead of directly accessing global arrays. In this case it would be

```
$submit = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'submit');
$students = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'Students');

if(isset($submit)) {
    echo $students;
}
```

[Example](https://www.phparch.com/2010/07/never-use-_get-again/)

Comment: THANKS! that's so simple.

However, I want to change the option value to query the whole column of that row.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly do like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   echo $_POST['Students'];
}
```

Or you can use `print_r` to resolved your confusion:

```
print_r($result);
```

Comment: How do I show the rest of the columns of that row? cause I also want to show the id, name, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Final, etc on the result.